# Syncfusion dropdown Enter Button select the first value of the dropdownlist

Tags: syncfusion

When clicking on enter button in a Syncfusion drop-down widget, the first value in the drop-down is selected automatically,
while the tab button select the choosen value, the enter button select always the first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, first dropdown list item value is selected & focused on opening the dropdown popup, so press the enter key, its automatically selected the first value. This is the default behavior of Drop-down List component.

Please let us know, if you have any concern on this behavior and clearly explain the tab key press related concerns.

Regards,
Ashokkumar B(Syncfusion).